# Tangent circles and finding diameters

Tags: geometry

**Here is a shaded crescent formed by two internally tangent circles. Point *O* is the the center of the larger circle. The width at points *B* and *B'* is five units. At point *A*, the width is 9 units. Find the lengths of the two circle's diameters.**

[image]

I have included the image that was given. 
Let *$r_1$* and *$d_1$* refer to the radius and diameter of the larger circle and let *$r_2$* and *$d_2$* refer to the radius and diameter of the smaller circle.

*mBO*=*$r_1$*= x+5

*mCO*=*$r_1$*-9

*mOD*= 4.5, because that is where the center of the smaller circle is. Since the two circles are touching and width of the crescent at *A* is 9. So, the line drawn in from *D* would be the radius of the smaller circle.

A right triangle is formed, so I could the use Pythagorean Theorem to find *$r_2$*.

So:

*$r_1$*= *x*+5

*$d_1$*= 2 *x* +10

*$r_2$*= *x*+4.5

*$d_2$*= 2 *x* +9

The problem is that I don't know where to go from here. Am I even on the right track? Any help on how to finish the problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have it.

$r_2 = OB = x + 5 = \sqrt{r_1^2 - (9/2)^2} + 5$

$r_2 = OA = 9 + OC = 9 + r_1 - (9/2) = r_1 + 9/2$

So $\sqrt{r_1^2 -(9/2)^2} = r_1 - 1/2 \implies r_1^2 - 81/4 = r_1^2 + 1/4 -r_1 \implies r_1 = 41/2$.

$r_2 = 41/2 + 9/2 = 25$.

Answer (score 1):

From the radii you have:

$r_2 = r_1 + 4.5$

From the internal right triangle you have:

$(r_2 - 5)^2 + 4.5^2 = r_1^2$.

Solve!

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. Why does $r_2$=$r_1$+4.5? Wouldn't it be $r_2$=$r_1$-4.5? Also, after I find $r_2$, what do I do?

Comment: Dana is right how can you assert$r_2=r_1+4.5$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let OC=$a$ and you have $x$
So now we have$$x+5=9+a\tag1$$
and
because 
$$4.5+a=r_2$$By applying pythagorus theorem:-
$$(4.5+a)^2-4.5^2=x^2\tag2$$
Now solve equations (1.) and (2.) for the factors $x$ and $a$ and
put in the equation :-
$$r_1=x+5=9+a$$
and 
$$r_2=4.5+a$$
There you go........

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use the [Intersecting Chord Theorem](http://www.mathopenref.com/chordsintersecting.html) (ICT). This is one of those simple results, like *Pythagoras's Theorem* that we learn at school, but then forget.

Looking at the outer circle in the picture below, the [ICT](http://www.mathopenref.com/chordsintersecting.html) tells us, unsurprisingly, that $\|OA\| \times \|OC\| = \|OB\| \times \|OD\|$. Looking at the inner circle in the picture below, the ICT tells us that $\|OE\|\times \|OC\| = \|OF\| \times \|OG\|$.

Assuming that the radius of the outer circle is $r$, we apply the [ICT](http://www.mathopenref.com/chordsintersecting.html) to the inner circle to get:
$$\|OE\|\times \|OC\| = \|OF\| \times \|OG\|$$
$$(r-9)\times r = (r-5) \times (r-5)$$
$$r^2-9r = r^2 - 10r + 25$$
$$r=25$$
The radius of the outer circle is $25$, and so it circumference is $50$.

The circumference of the inner circle is $\|EC\|=(r-9)+r=2r-9=41$.

[image]